# how to create a multiple ForeignKey fields in a view create and save to database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, foreign-keys

[image: In the create view i cam make multiples fileds but i in the admin display only one]

**First of all, I appreciate your help and time**

I would like to save all the 'equipamento' fields in the database instead of just one!

When I save the form, it doesn't give any errors, but looking in the django admin, it is only saving one equipment field and not 2 or 3, because when I click on the green button (success) in the create view it generates 2 new fields to choose from.

**Moldel admin**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Saida
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Saida)
```

**Moldel SAIDA**

```
# flake8: noqa
from django.db import models
from funcionario.models import Funcionario 
from estoque.models import Estoque


class Saida(models.Model):
    funcionario = models.ForeignKey(Funcionario, verbose_name='Funcionário', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    observacao = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Observações')
    equipamento = models.ForeignKey(Estoque, verbose_name='Equipamento', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    quantidade_saida = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Retirada N. {self.pk}'
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Saida estoque'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Saida estoque'
```

**SAIDA VIEW CREATE**

```
def create(request):
    form_action = reverse('saida:create')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = saidaForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        context = {
            'form': form,
            'form_action': form_action,
        }

        if form.is_valid():
            saida = form
            saida.save()

            return redirect('saida:lista')

        return render(
            request,
            'saida/create.html',
            context
        )

    context = {
        'form': saidaForm(),
        'form_action': form_action,
    }

    return render(
        request,
        'saida/create.html',
        context
    )



class saidaForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Saida
        fields = "__all__"
```

**CREATE.HMTL**

```
<h2>Nova Requisição</h2>

<form 
  action=""
  method="POST"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
>
{% csrf_token %}


   
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="{{ form2.equipamento.id_for_label }}" class="col-6"><strong>{{ form.funcionario.label }}</strong></label>
            {{ form.funcionario}}
         
            <label for="{{ form2.quantidade.id_for_label }}"class="col-6"><strong>{{ form.observacao.label }}</strong></label>
            {{ form.observacao }}
        </div>
  
    <h2>Itens da Requisição</h2>

    
    <div id="estoque" class="form-group ">

        
      <div id="item-estoque"class="form-group " >
      <label for="{{ form2.equipamento.id_for_label }}" class="col-6"><strong>{{ form.equipamento.label }}</strong></label>
      {{ form.equipamento }}
   
      <label for="{{ form2.quantidade.id_for_label }}"class="col-6"><strong>{{ form.quantidade.label }}</strong></label>
      {{ form.quantidade_saida }}
      </div>
    


  </div>
  <div class="form-content" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <span id="add-item" class="btn btn-success " style="margin-top: 10px;">
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Adicionar item
    </span>
  </div>


  <div class="form-content">
    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Cadastrar</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: A `ForeignKey` is a `ManyToOne` field.  I think you have it set up the opposite way that you intended.  The way you have it now, you will therefore have MANY `Saida` objects to ONE `Estoque` object.  Do the reverse.  Make `Saida` a `ForeignKey` of your `Estoque` model.